# Strolling Around In vs Strolling around

Tags: grammaticality

I like strolling around cities that I travel to.

Vs

I like strolling around in the cities that I travel to.

Is in necessary here or is strolling around itself self sufficient ?

Comment: There is not much difference. Someone very pedantic might say the first one is ambiguous: it could also mean that you walk around the outer perimeter of the city. But normal people would understand both sentences fine.